# Hybridauth (redirect to website, without login fb)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I still learning about this hybridauth, i follow instruction from this [website](http://onlinecoderank.com/login-facebook-twitter-google-using-hybridauth-php/).

When i try login in facebook it's redirect to my website (not yet login in fb), it's should be redirect to login facebook after that show profile (login-with.php).

and my href like this http://website.com/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1467301785

login.html :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body align="center">

    <div align="center">
    <h1>Login with Facebook,Twitter & Google</h1>

    <a href="login-with.php?provider=Facebook"><img src='facebook.png'></img></a> <br><br>
    <a href="login-with.php?provider=Twitter"><img src='twitter.png'></img></a> <br><br>
    <a href="login-with.php?provider=Google"><img src='google.png'></img></a><br><br>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

login-with.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    include('Hybrid/Auth.php');
    if(isset($_GET['provider']))
    {
        $provider = $_GET['provider'];

        try{

        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $authProvider = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);

        $user_profile = $authProvider->getUserProfile();

        if($user_profile && isset($user_profile->identifier))
        {

            echo "<br> <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br/>";
            echo "<b>Hello Dear</b> :".$user_profile->displayName."<br>";
            echo "<b>Profile URL</b> :".$user_profile->profileURL."<br>";
            echo "<img src='".$user_profile->photoURL."'/><br>";
            echo "<b>Email</b> :".$user_profile->email."<br>";                                              
            echo "<b>Image</b> :".$user_profile->photoURL."<br> ";
        }           

        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        { 

             switch( $e->getCode() )
             {
                    case 0 : echo "Unspecified error."; break;
                    case 1 : echo "Hybridauth configuration error."; break;
                    case 2 : echo "Provider not properly configured."; break;
                    case 3 : echo "Unknown or disabled provider."; break;
                    case 4 : echo "Missing provider application credentials."; break;
                    case 5 : echo "Authentication failed. "
                                     . "The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.";
                             break;
                    case 6 : echo "User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected "
                                     . "to the provider and he should to authenticate again.";
                             $twitter->logout();
                             break;
                    case 7 : echo "User not connected to the provider.";
                             $twitter->logout();
                             break;
                    case 8 : echo "Provider does not support this feature."; break;
            }

            // well, basically your should not display this to the end user, just give him a hint and move on..
            echo "<br /><br /><b>Original error message:</b> " . $e->getMessage();

            echo "<hr /><h3>Trace</h3> <pre>" . $e->getTraceAsString() . "</pre>";

        }

    }
?>
```

Config.php :

```
<?php
    $config =array(
            "base_url" => "http://website.com/",
            "providers" => array(
                // openid providers
                "OpenID" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Yahoo" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "AOL" => array(
                    "enabled" => true
                ),
                "Google" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => ""),
                ),
                "Facebook" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                    "scope" => "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown",
                ),
                "Twitter" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => ""),
                    "includeEmail" => false
                ),
                // windows live
                "Live" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "LinkedIn" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("key" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
                "Foursquare" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "", "secret" => "")
                ),
            ),
            "debug_mode" => false,
            "debug_file" => "",
);
```

Where i did mistake?? thanks for advance.